# Reinstall versions of software not found in repositories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I recently installed the utouch-daily PPA, and it's given me some problems.

How can I revert to the packages available in the default repository? I've removed the repository from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, now how can I revert to the ones now available from the other normal repositories available on my system?

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59443/how-can-i-revert-back-from-an-upgrade-to-the-proposed-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try ppa-purge.

For that, you need to add the PPA to your system so that ppa-purge can analyse the packages installed from that PPA.

First of all, install ppa-purge: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

Then, run a command similar to this: `sudo ppa-purge utouch-daily`

*Replace utouch-daily with the actual name of PPA.

After running ppa-purge, run `sudo apt-get update` and the packages will be reverted to the default repository.

Comment: Nice, thanks, I haven't been able to try it, but this is definitely a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have removed the repo, then you should `apt-get update` to update your local repo tree, and `apt-get install utouch` to reinstall this program, it'll revert to the default version